# How to call the div with the higher z-index to the top on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have 2 drawers/menus on the right of my site, 1 for the cart and 1 for the product quick view option.

I've built my theme using the [Shopify Timber Framework](https://github.com/Shopify/Timber) and the drawers currently slide open (#PageContainer moves to the left on click to reveal the drawer).

I need to alter the JS so that on click the z-index changes so that the correct drawer being called is highest in the stack.

I'm not great with JS so not sure if this is a simple task?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code is as follows:

**Update**: Link to [Dev Store](http://test-store-980.myshopify.com)

JS:

```
timber.Drawers = (function () {
var Drawer = function (id, position, options) {
var defaults = {
  close: '.js-drawer-close',
  open: '.js-drawer-open-' + position,
  openClass: 'js-drawer-open',
  dirOpenClass: 'js-drawer-open-' + position
};

this.$nodes = {
  parent: $('body, html'),
  page: $('#PageContainer'),
  moved: $('.is-moved-by-drawer')
};

this.config = $.extend(defaults, options);
this.position = position;

this.$drawer = $('#' + id);

if (!this.$drawer.length) {
  return false;
}

this.drawerIsOpen = false;
this.init();
};

Drawer.prototype.init = function () {
$(this.config.open).on('click', $.proxy(this.open, this));
this.$drawer.find(this.config.close).on('click', $.proxy(this.close, this));
};

Drawer.prototype.open = function (evt) {
// Keep track if drawer was opened from a click, or called by another function
var externalCall = false;

// Prevent following href if link is clicked
if (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
} else {
  externalCall = true;
}

// Without this, the drawer opens, the click event bubbles up to $nodes.page
// which closes the drawer.
if (evt && evt.stopPropagation) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  // save the source of the click, we'll focus to this on close
  this.$activeSource = $(evt.currentTarget);
}

if (this.drawerIsOpen && !externalCall) {
  return this.close();
}

// Add is-transitioning class to moved elements on open so drawer can have
// transition for close animation
this.$nodes.moved.addClass('is-transitioning');
this.$drawer.prepareTransition();

this.$nodes.parent.addClass(this.config.openClass + ' ' + this.config.dirOpenClass);
this.drawerIsOpen = true;

// Run function when draw opens if set
if (this.config.onDrawerOpen && typeof(this.config.onDrawerOpen) == 'function') {
  if (!externalCall) {
    this.config.onDrawerOpen();
  }
}

if (this.$activeSource && this.$activeSource.attr('aria-expanded')) {
  this.$activeSource.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
}

// Lock scrolling on mobile
this.$nodes.page.on('touchmove.drawer', function () {
  return false;
});

this.$nodes.page.on('click.drawer', $.proxy(function () {
  this.close();
  return false;
}, this));
};

Drawer.prototype.close = function () {
if (!this.drawerIsOpen) { // don't close a closed drawer
  return;
}

// deselect any focused form elements
$(document.activeElement).trigger('blur');

// Ensure closing transition is applied to moved elements, like the nav
this.$nodes.moved.prepareTransition({ disableExisting: true });
this.$drawer.prepareTransition({ disableExisting: true });

this.$nodes.parent.removeClass(this.config.dirOpenClass + ' ' + this.config.openClass);

this.drawerIsOpen = false;

this.$nodes.page.off('.drawer');
};
return Drawer;
})();
```

CSS / SASS:

```
.js-drawer-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 ($gutter / 2) ($gutter / 2);
  max-width: 95%;
  z-index: $zindexDrawer;
  color: $colorDrawerText;
  background-color: $colorDrawers;
  @include transition($drawerTransition);

  a {
    color: $colorDrawerText;

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
    opacity: 0.7;
    }
  }

  input,
  textarea {
  border-color: $colorDrawerBorder;
  }
}

.drawer-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.drawer--has-fixed-footer .drawer__inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drawer--left {
  width: $drawerNavWidth;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid $colorDrawerBorder;

  .js-drawer-open-left & {
    display: block;

.lt-ie9 & {
  left: 0;
  }
 }
}

.drawer--right {
  width: $drawerCartWidth;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid $colorDrawerBorder;

  .js-drawer-open-right & {
    display: block;

    .lt-ie9 & {
      right: 0;
    }
  }
}

.drawer--right-two {
  width: $drawerQuickShopWidth;
  right: -$drawerQuickShopWidth;
  border-left: 1px solid $colorDrawerBorder;

  .js-drawer-open-right-two & {
    display: block;
    @include transform(translateX(-$drawerQuickShopWidth));

    .lt-ie9 & {
      right: 0;
    }
  }
}

#PageContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.is-moved-by-drawer {
  @include transition($drawerTransition);

  .js-drawer-open-left & {
    @include transform(translateX($drawerNavWidth));
  }

  .js-drawer-open-right & {
    @include transform(translateX(-$drawerCartWidth));
  }

  .js-drawer-open-right-two & {
    @include transform(translateX(-$drawerQuickShopWidth));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not CSS. What is it, less, sass?

Comment: Apologies I've been using the Timber framework which uses SASS.

Comment: Don't post Sass unless there is a problem compiling Sass to the correct CSS.  Only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: I think the problem is more to do with JS but I thought it might be helpful to see the CSS to better understand how I have everything currently. Is the CSS/SASS not relevant?

Comment: the SASS is not CSS yet, the rendered CSS is useful to us, the SASS is less so because we have to manually evaluate it.

Comment: Can we get a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I see, apologies as SASS is quite new to me. I'm not great with JS this piece came with the Timber framework so I'm not really sure where to even begin.

Comment: can you link your website, or provide a visual example to help debug your issue?

Comment: Here's a link to my dev store http://test-store-980.myshopify.com - if you click 'Buy' on each product its meant to open the quick view. Click 'Add to Cart' (product page) or 'Cart' on any page and it reveals the quick cart. Currently the quick view is sitting on top of the quick shop. Many thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

Give your two drawers a common class, then query the document for which one has been clicked. 
Set the z-index of both drawers, then set the z-index of the clicked drawer to something higher!

```
window.onload = function() {

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.drawers'), function(el) { 
        el.addEventListener('click', drawerOpened); 
    });

        function drawerOpened()
        {
            $('.drawers').css('z-index', '50');
            $(this).css('z-index', '60');
        }
    )};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does the z-index set in the CSS for both drawers need to be different or the same? Both my drawers have the class '.drawer' would that work in this case?

Comment: The drawer that you want to display has to have a higher index. In order to switch between them, the above function listens for which one is clicked , resets both to 50, and then sets the clicked one to 60 so it is higher, and will therefore be displayed! :) Yes, that class should work fine!

Comment: So currently .drawer is set to have a z-index of 10 so that both drawers on the right sit underneath the main body of content which then slides across to reveal them. They are currently therefore being stacked in order of hierachy. I've tried your JS but nothing seems to be happening, any ideas why this might be? Does .drawer need to be on the button that triggers or the actual drawer being revealed?